# model_type in Django template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am learning Django from a book called Web Development with Django. In one of the activities there is a tag in one of the templates as below:

```
{% block title %}
{% if instance %}
Editing {{ model_type }} {{ instance }}
{% else %}
New {{ model_type }}
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

What is the `model_type`? I have never seen this tag before. It is not in any of the view.py functions or anywhere else.

Comment: there is nothing named these. they are must sent through `views.py`

Answer (score 1):

`Django` works on [`MVT`](https://www.javatpoint.com/django-mvt)<sup>[javapoint]</sup> design pattern, so whether `instances,querysets` must be passed through `view`, whether hardcoded or fetching from any `Model`.

> `model_type` is not any inbuilt property or anyting, they are passed through views.

Consider 1st example (Things are hardcoded):

> Create a project and create an application `home`, through `python manage.py startapp home`. create `templates` folder for html files inside app at the path `home/templates/home/index.html`, this means [`template namespacing`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial03/)<sup>[django-doc]</sup>

> `Note:` You don't need to give `templates` in `APP_DIRS` in `settings.py`, they are only given when we place all the templates from all apps, in outside folder, same for `static`.

index.html

```
<body>
    <h2>Name : {{name}}</h2>
    <h2>Technology : {{technology}}</h2>
</body>
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def home(request):
    context = {
        'name': 'reza',
        'technology': 'django'
    }
    return render(request, 'home/index.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
urlpatterns = [
    path('home/', views.home, name='home')
]
```

In above example, things are hardcoded but we generally use in loops.

Consider 2nd example (data is from database):

> In this example, I have created a model and data will come dynamically.

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class StudentDetail(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200)
    total_marks = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Record of {self.name} was added."
```

Now, register it in `admin.py` to see in the admin interface.

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import StudentDetail

@admin.register(StudentDetail)
class StudentDetailAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'name', 'email', 'total_marks']
```

Now, run `python manage.py makemigrations`, then run `python manage.py migrate`.

Now, create superuser to add some data manually, by `python manage.py createsuperuser`.

Then, add 3 or 4 records in database through admin interface.

Now, make your views to retrieve objects dynamically.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import StudentDetail


def home(request):
    all_students = StudentDetail.objects.all()
    context = {
        'all_students': all_students

    }
    return render(request, 'home/index.html', context)
```

index.html

```
<body>
    <table border='3px' cellpadding='1px' cellspacing='5px' style='text-align:center;'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Total Marks</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for student in all_students  %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{student.name}}</td>
                <td>{{student.email}}</td>
                <td>{{student.total_marks}}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>    
</body>
```

In the above way, work is done, I'll recommend you to directly read and learn everything from [`django-doc`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/). At first level starts with [`topic-guides`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/), and also see how the [`documentation`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/#how-the-documentation-is-organized) is organized.

Comment: Thank you Sunderam for your comprehensive explanation. Later I realized it was my mistake. Model_type was in the view ( in the context).